# How to display differences between two strings with color etc like in diff format?

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I would like to display in some output the differences between two strings that makes it super easy for the user to understand. For example:

1. SkyWalker
2. kWalkerr

would output:

[image]

Is there a way to do that in Python, reusing some library? I checked out the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) but didn't find how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) for this:

```
a = 'SkyWalker'
b = 'kWalkerr'

m = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=a, b=b)

for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in m.get_opcodes():
    if tag == 'replace':
        print(f'<del>{a[i1:i2]}</del>', end='')
        print(f'<ins>{b[j1:j2]}</ins>', end='')
    if tag == 'delete':
        print(f'<del>{a[i1:i2]}</del>', end='')
    if tag == 'insert':
        print(f'<ins>{b[j1:j2]}</ins>', end='')
    if tag == 'equal':
        print(f'{a[i1:i2]}', end='')
```

Result:

```html
<del>S</del>k<del>y</del>Walker<ins>r</ins>
```